# Install TeXLive on OpenSUSE

Tags: latex, tex, opensuse, suse, tex-live

I have an OpenSUSE Leap 15.2. operating system.

I have downloaded this `texlive.ymp` file from [this link](https://software.opensuse.org/package/texlive).

I go to YaST > Software Manager (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341415/latex-installation-on-suse-linux)), but then I don't know what to do. Where can I find this `texlive.ymp` file?

[image]

I have also tried to do `sudo zypper install texlive-latex` as suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/8al7vn/how_to_install_latex/), but after I insert my password I get (loosely translated):

```
System management is blocked by the application with pid 14461 (/usr/bin/ruby.ruby2.5).
Please close this app before trying again.
```

EDIT:

So the solution for me has been:

1. Go to [here](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and download `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`
2. Go to the folder where it has been downloaded and extract the file
3. `cd` to the extracted folder
4. `perl install-tl`
5. `Enter command: i`

If you don't have permission to edit `/usr/local/`, go there and run `sudo mkdir texlive`, then `chmod +rwx texlive`.

Comment: I suggest to use vanilla texlive from https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html instead of the one packaged for your distribution. This will have all packages and be more up-to-date.

Comment: If I do this I get: `Enter command: i
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2022
install-tl: mkdir(/usr/local/texlive/) failed for tree /usr/local/texlive/2022: Permission denied at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 1142, <STDIN> line 1.`

Comment: Do you have writing rights to `/usr/local/`? Otherwise you might have to create the folder `/usr/local/texlive/` with sudo and then give you writing access to this folder

Comment: Okay, now I've done `Enter command: i` and it works, but it's expected to take 1h 12min. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes. texlive is something like 5 GB (depending on the selection of packages) -- this takes a while